# Filtering observations using multivariate column conditions

Tags: r, filter, conditional-statements

I'm not very experienced R user, so seek advice how to optimize what I've build and in which direction to move on.

I have one **reference** data frame, it contains four columns with integer values and one ID.

```
df <- matrix(ncol=5,nrow = 10)
colnames(df) <- c("A","B","C","D","ID")
# df
for (i in 1:10){
        df[i,1:4] <- sample(1:5,4, replace = TRUE)
}
df <- data.frame(df)
df$ID <- make.unique(rep(LETTERS,length.out=10),sep='')
df
 A B C D ID
1  2 4 3 5  A
2  5 1 3 5  B
3  3 3 5 3  C
4  4 3 1 5  D
5  2 1 2 5  E
6  5 4 4 5  F
7  4 4 3 3  G
8  2 1 5 5  H
9  4 4 1 3  I
10 4 2 2 2  J
```

Second data frame has manual input, it's user input, I want to turn it into shiny app later on, that's why also I'm asking for optimization, because my code doesn't seem very neat to me.

```
df.man <- data.frame(matrix(ncol=5,nrow=1))
colnames(df.man) <- c("A","B","C","D","ID")
df.man$ID <- c("man")
df.man$A <- 4
df.man$B <- 4
df.man$C <- 3
df.man$D <- 4
df.man
 A B C D  ID
 4 4 3 4 man
```

I want to filter rows from reference sequentially, following the rules:

If there is exact match in a whole row between **reference** table  and **manual** than extract this(those)  from reference and show me that row, if not then reduce number of matching columns from right to left until there is a match but not between less then two variables(columns A,B).

So with my limited knowledge I've wrote this:

```
# subtraction manual from reference 
df <- df %>% dplyr::mutate(Adiff=A-df.man$A)%>%
        dplyr::mutate(Bdiff=B-df.man$B)%>% 
        dplyr::mutate(Cdiff=C-df.man$C) %>% 
        dplyr::mutate(Ddiff=D-df.man$D)

# check manually how much in a row has zero difference and filter those
ifelse(nrow(df%>%filter(Adiff==0 & Bdiff==0 & Cdiff==0 & Ddiff==0)) != 0,
       df0<-df%>%filter(Adiff==0 & Bdiff==0 & Cdiff==0 & Ddiff==0),
       ifelse(nrow(df%>%filter(Adiff==0 & Bdiff==0 & Cdiff==0)) != 0,
              df0<-df%>%filter(Adiff==0 & Bdiff==0 & Cdiff==0),
              ifelse(nrow(df%>%filter(Adiff==0 & Bdiff==0)) != 0,
              df0<-df%>%filter(Adiff==0 & Bdiff==0),
              "less then two exact match")
       ))

tbl_df(df0[,1:5]) 

# A tibble: 1 x 5
      A     B     C     D ID   
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <chr>
1     4     4     3     3 G
```

It works and found ID **G** but looks ugly to me. So the **first question** is - What would be recommended way to improve this? Are there any functions, packages or smth I'm missing?

**Second question** - I want to complicate condition.

Imagine we have reference data set.

```
A B C D ID
2 4 3 5  A
5 1 3 5  B
3 3 5 3  C
4 3 1 5  D
2 1 2 5  E
5 4 4 5  F
4 4 3 3  G
2 1 5 5  H
4 4 1 3  I
4 2 2 2  J
```

Manual input is

```
A B C D ID
4 4 2 2 man
```

Filtering rules should be following:

1. If there is exact match in a whole row between **reference** table  and **manual** than extract this(those)  from reference and show me that row, if not then reduce number of matching columns from right to left until there is a match but not between less then two variables(columns A,B).
2. From those rows where I have only two variable matches filter those which has ± 1 difference in  columns to the right. So I should have filtered case **G** and **I** from reference table from the example above.

*keep going the way I did above, I would do the following:*

```
ifelse(nrow(df0%>%filter(Cdiff %in% (-1:1) & Ddiff %in% (-1:1)))>0,
       df01 <- df0%>%filter(Cdiff %in% (-1:1) & Ddiff %in% (-1:1)),
       ifelse(nrow(df0%>%filter(Cdiff %in% (-1:1)))>0,
              df01<- df0%>%filter(Cdiff %in% (-1:1)),
       "NA"))
```

It will be about 11 columns at the end, but I assume it doesn't matter so much.

Keeping in mind this objective - how would you suggest to proceed?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify the second rule for the second question? This applies when you have "only four variable matches" --- but it looks like you apply the +/-1 difference to G and I that have 2 matches? Did you mean only "2 variable matches" A & B?

Comment: Yes, I think I messed it up, I mean 2 variable matches in that particular example but in future I will have 11 variables and want minimum 4 matching. I'll update text in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a lot to sort through, but I have some ideas that might be helpful.

First, you could keep your `df` a matrix, and use row names for your letters. Something like:

```
set.seed(2)

df

  A B C D
A 5 1 5 1
B 4 5 1 2
C 3 1 3 2
D 3 1 1 4
E 3 1 5 3
F 1 5 5 2
G 2 3 4 3
H 1 1 5 1
I 2 4 5 5
J 4 2 5 5
```

And for demonstration, you could use a vector for `manual` as this is input:

```
# Complete match example
vec.man <- c(3, 1, 5, 3)
```

To check for complete matches between the manual input and reference (all 4 columns), with all numbers, you can do:

```
df[apply(df, 1, function(x) all(x == vec.man)), ]

A B C D 
3 1 5 3
```

If you don't have a complete match, would calculate differences between `df` and `vec.man`:

```
# Change example vec.man
vec.man <- c(3, 1, 5, 2)

df.diff <- sweep(df, 2, vec.man)

   A B  C  D
A  2 0  0 -1
B  1 4 -4  0
C  0 0 -2  0
D  0 0 -4  2
E  0 0  0  1
F -2 4  0  0
G -1 2 -1  1
H -2 0  0 -1
I -1 3  0  3
J  1 1  0  3
```

The diffs that start with and continue with 0 will be your best matches (same as looking from right to left iteratively). Then, your best match is the column of the first non-zero element in each row:

```
df.best <- apply(df.diff, 1, function(x) which(x!=0)[1])

A B C D E F G H I J 
1 1 3 3 4 1 1 1 1 1
```

You can see that the best match is `E` which was non-zero in the 4th column (last column did not match). You can extract rows that have 4 in `df.best` as your best matches:

```
df.match <- df[which(df.best == max(df.best, na.rm = T)), ]

A B C D 
3 1 5 3
```

Finally, if you want all the rows with closest match +/- 1 if only 2 match, you could check for number of best matches (should be 3). Then, compare differences with vector `c(0,0,1)` which would imply 2 matches then 3rd column off by +/- 1:

```
# Example vec.man with only 2 matches
vec.man <- c(3, 1, 6, 9)

> df.match
  A B C D
C 3 1 3 2
D 3 1 1 4
E 3 1 5 3

if (max(df.best, na.rm = T) == 3) {
  vec.alt = c(0, 0, 1)
  df[apply(df.diff[,1:3], 1, function(x) all(abs(x) == vec.alt)), ]
}

A B C D 
3 1 5 3
```

This should be scalable for 11 columns and 4 matches.

To generalize for different numbers of columns, @IlyaT suggested:

```
n.cols <- max(df.best, na.rm=TRUE) 
vec.alt <- c(rep(0, each=n.cols-1), 1)
```

Comment: Looks like there should be comma at the very last expression `if (max(df.best, na.rm = T) == 3) {
  vec.alt = c(0, 0, 1)
  df[apply(df.diff[,1:3], 1, function(x) all(abs(x) == vec.alt)),]
}`

Comment: Added comma at the end

Comment: Thanks @Ben, I've tried to make last part a bit more general, so start from max number of matches. `n.cols <- max(df.best,na.rm=TRUE) #then create vector vec.alt <- c(rep (0,each=n.cols-1),1)` and then check match with this, thanks a lot!

Comment: Thank you for adding this - will edit answer to include as well.